# Values of each bin

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

i got following problem:

`hist, edges = np.histogram(data, bins=50)`

How can i access the values of each bin? I wanted to calculate the avg of each bin.

Thanks

Comment: 'hist' *is* the values of each bin, what's the problem?

Comment: i got a 1d list of errors. I wanted to show the avg. error in each bin plus std.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Can you provide a [mcve] show the desired outcome?

Comment: 'hist' shows me how much data points are in this bucket. But not the actually values

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binned_statistic.html, or np.digitize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this function does what you want:

```
import numpy as np

def binned_mean(values, edges):
    values = np.asarray(values)
    # Classify values into bins
    dig = np.digitize(values, edges)
    # Mask values out of bins
    m = (dig > 0) & (dig < len(edges))
    values = values[m]
    dig = dig[m] - 1
    # Binned sum of values
    nbins = len(edges) - 1
    s = np.zeros(nbins, dtype=values.dtype)
    np.add.at(s, dig, values)
    # Binned count of values
    count = np.zeros(nbins, dtype=np.int32)
    np.add.at(count, dig, 1)
    # Means
    return s / count.clip(min=1)
```

Example:

```
print(binned_mean([1.2, 1.8, 2.1, 2.4, 2.7], [1, 2, 3]))
# [1.5 2.4]
```

There is a slight difference with the histogram in this function though, as `np.digitize` considers all bins to be half-closed (either right or left), unlike `np.histogram` which considers the last edge to be closed.

Comment: YES, that's what Im looking for. Thank you! Cant give you a up vote for your answer because of my missing reputation.

Comment: @NexusHero No worries. You should still be able to mark the answer as accepted if you feel it solved your problem, although maybe, as suggested in the comments, you find [`scipy.stats.binned_statistic`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binned_statistic.html) more convenient.